# How to migrate 4.1 primary user's app data to new 4.2 secondary user?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, multi-user

My wife has been playing games (Angry Birds Star Wars if that makes a difference) on my Nexus 7 which I have just updated from 4.1 to 4.2. Android 4.2 lets you have multiple users on a single device, so I would like to create a new user account on this device which has all of her game saves.

Without root, is it possible to migrate specific applications data to a new user account on the same device?

Answer (score 1):

[This post on Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/07/19/rovio-account-lets-angry-birds-players-save-and-sync-progress-across-devices-coming-to-more-games-soon/) basically says they will be offering accounts soon to the Star Wars game to backup data.

Answer (score 0):

Find the data files for you applications and then upload to something like Google Drive or Dropbox.

Once you have upgraded, download the files.

Comment: Do you have any steps to do so?