# How can I move application user data (user specific settings, savegames, ...) to a different user?

Tags: multi-user, 4.2-jelly-bean

I have a tablet with Android 4.2 and would like to copy/move the application **user** data (savegames, ...) from one user to another. I have root. Which directory do I need to move/copy. And do I have to care about the permissions?

Comment: I cannot say for sure (have yet to dig into the new directory structures with 4.2+). But a *good guess* comes from where the data are usually stored (`/data/data/com.myapp`, where `com.myapp` is the app's package name) and the fact that JB uses numerics (like e.g. `/mnt/sdcard0`) for user specific stuff: Check if there's something similar, I'd guess it will be something like `/data/data0/com.myapp` for the first user).

Comment: See also: [How to migrate 4.1 primary user's app data to new 4.2 secondary user?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33418/16575) / [How to migrate applications to other user account without downloading the applications again?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33798/16575)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the app Titanium Backup.
1. Install Titanium Backup on the first user profile
2. Make a backup of the app or apps from the first user.
3. Install Titanium Backup on the second user profile
4. Restore data only to the second user profile

That should do the trick.

For instructions on how to use Titanium Backup look here: http://www.titaniumtrack.com/kb/titanium-backup-kb/titanium-backup-user-guide.html#backup

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do it by go backup app, use go backup to backup apk+data, than copy the backed up apk +data in folder external storage/go backup, than make a copy to your friend mmc, than install go backup on your friend  phone and restore the app via go backup, i have not try it before, but i think it will work 100%, if you succes with this trick please give a reply