# Transfer data from one user to another in 4.3

Tags: nexus-7, 4.3-jelly-bean, multi-user

I have the Nexus 7, and I just updated to 4.3, and I'm creating restricted profiles for my kids. They use to play in my main profile, and they progressed a lot in several games and, when they access their new user, they have to start over. Is there anyway to migrate the application data from my main user to the restricted users? I'm not rooted. Tks

Comment: Possibly related and helpful: [How to migrate 4.1 primary user's app data to new 4.2 secondary user?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33418/16575) / [Converting an existing user to a restricted profile](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/50223/16575) / [How to migrate applications to other user account without downloading the applications again?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33798/16575) / [How can I move application user data to a different user?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36951/16575) (also see the "Related" section of this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem with my kid's profile. Finally solved, but it required root access.

This is what I did:

1. Close all running app instances.
2. From command prompt start ADB shell:

   ```
   c:\> adb shell
   ```
3. Switch to root user (your device must be rooted):

   ```
   shell> su
   ```
4. Go to in target profile directory:

   ```
   root> cd /data/user/[profile_user_id]
   ```

   For example: `profile_user_id` is `10` for first restricted profile.
5. Rename app directory (to have a back up copy)

   ```
   root> mv [app_dir] [app_dir].old
   ```
6. Copy app data from main profile (id=0) to new profile:

   ```
   root> cp -r /data/user/0/[app_dir] .
   ```
7. Change owner for files just copied:

   ```
   root> find [app_dir] | xargs chown [app_user]:[app_group]
   ```
8. Restart device (not sure if it is really needed).

Comment: I'd just make a small adjustment to Tonto|One's answer: use "cp -a" rather than "cp -r". This preserves symlinks (typically to a lib directory) and avoids the need for the chown step.

Comment: `chown` is required to set the owner to the *new user*. Also, there's a `-R` (recursive) option so running find isn't necessary. `chown -R  [app_user]:[app_group] [app_dir]` (`ls -l [app_dir]` to know what they are before step 5)