# How to copy app data to another user profile (on same device)?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, accounts

I've created an extra user profile for my kid and want to move his game progress (such as Angry Birds and the like) over to his profile, but am unsure how to go about doing this. The profile is not a 'restricted' sub-profile.

Running Lollipop --

This was about as close as I could find for a reference, but am unsure if this is even the best method, and how to execute the chown command (what are the app_user and app_group placeholders populated with? the values from ls -l?).

> from command prompt start ADB shell:
>
> **adb shell**
>
> switch to root user (your device must be rooted):
>
> shell> **su**
>
> go to in target profile directory:
>
> root> **cd /data/user/[profile_user_id]**
>
> *For example: profile_user_id==10 for first restricted profile.*
>
> rename directory (to have a back up copy)
>
> root> **mv [app_dir] [app_dir].old**
>
> copy app data from main profile (id=0) to new profile:
>
> root> **cp -r /data/user/0/[app_dir] /data/user/[new profile
>   id]/[app_dir]**
>
> change owner for files just copied:
>
> root> **find [app_dir] | xargs chown [app_user]:[app_group]**
>
> [Transfer data from one user to another in 4.3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51467/transfer-data-from-one-user-to-another-in-4-3)